# Read TXT downloaded OneDrive

Tags: c#

I'm doing a donwload OneDrive txt file with the code:

var downloadOperationResult = await cliente.DownloadAsync(idOfFile);

```
using (Stream downloadStream = downloadOperationResult.Stream)
{
    if (downloadStream != null)
    {                        
         //download completed
    }
}
```

And I am using the following code to read the downloaded file (In place of the comment:"//download completed")

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(downloadStream))
{
string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

But instead of reading the txt is reading the file properties.
Output:

```
{
"id":"file. + idFile
"from":{ 
"name":"myname",
"id":the id
},
"name": name of file
"description": ""
"parent_id": id of folder
(...)
```

Could anyone help me? 
(I'm developing for Windows Phone)

Answer (score 1):

To get the file content instead of the file meta data, add **"/content"** to the file ID

file meta data

```
path = "file.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!129"
```

file content

```
path = "file.8c8ce076ca27823f.8C8CE076CA27823F!129/content"
```

example:

```
LiveConnectClient liveClient = new LiveConnectClient(liveSession);
LiveDownloadOperation operation = 
             await liveClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(fileId + "/content");
var operationResult = await operation.StartAsync();

var fileContent = 
             await CustomMethod(await operationResult.GetRandomAccessStreamAsync());

return fileContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was asked a while ago but, someone may find value in the answer.  On Windows Phone you will want to handle file downloads Async.  This is to handle the case when a user may page away from an application.

You can find more info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659730.aspx

```
try
{
    LiveDownloadOperation operation = await connectClient.CreateBackgroundDownloadAsync(filePath);
    var result = await operation.StartAsync();
    // Handle result.
}
catch
{
    // Handle errors.
}
```